# Is there a way to deselect selections/clearSelection() for QListWidgets in PyQT6?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, pyqt6

I have a class whose function is to detect clicks on a QFrame. I used the QObject for this class function. See here

```
class MouseObserver(QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget and event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                print(event)
                ClearsSelection.UnselectionEvent()    #this is function i called for another class
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

And then this class below here, its job is supposed to clearSelection() for the QListWidget items previously selected.

```
class ClearsSelection(QListWidget, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, weedget):
        super().__init__(weedget)
        self.listWidget = weedget
        #self.weedget=QListWidgetItem(self)

    def UnselectionEvent(self, wee):
        if wee is self.listWidget and QItemSelectionModel.hasSelection():
                print(wee)
        return super().clearSelection(wee, self.listWidget)
```

Declaring this here is supposed to check for clicks and then if the QListWidgetsitems are selected, it clears the selection. I need this mechanism because by default, when you click an item, it sticks the selection. I need to be able to click on a frame and then the selection Deselect.

```
self.observer = MouseObserver(self.frame_41, self.listWidget)
```

Comment: Your code is quite convoluted and invalid, since: 1. you're calling an instance method as a class method; 2. `clearSelection()` also doesn't accept any argument; 3. subclassing from a QListWidget *and* a Ui form created for a main window doesn't make any sense. Besides, it's unclear why you want to clear a selection when *any* mouse press happens. Are you trying to achieve a *toggle* selection mode? If you need that, just use [`setSelectionMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop) with `MultiSelection`.

Comment: @musicamante  Yes. I am trying to achieve a toggle selection. I am actually using the ExtendedSelection and also i tried the MultiSelection too, and i don't like the fact that after multiple selection, i have to start toggling/click each item in order to deselect it. That is why i tried to implent a click on the frame which automatically clears the selections. And for the Ui_MainWindow, i just saw the mistake now. I was trying to calll a variable directly from my main window to see if it works.